# Pegar o caminho de uma imagem na Galeria

Tags: android

Como eu posso fazer para pegar o caminho da imagem que eu acabo de fazer o upload para depois salvar no banco de dados com o caminho?
Eu pego a imagem da Galeria, logo em seguida com essa imagem eu queria pegar o caminho e salvar no banco SQLite.
Sou meio leigo no assunto :(

```js
     ImageButton contactImgView;
        private String imagePath;

       public void tela_cuidador_cadastrar_tema(){
 
 setContentView(R.layout.tela_cuidador_cadastrar_tema);
 
 contactImgView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


    //Procura Imagem da galeria


    contactImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(View v){
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setType("image/*");
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
 
     }
    });       
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);
    if(resCode == RESULT_OK)    {
        if (reqCode == 1)
            contactImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
         Uri imageUri = data.getData();
         imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}

public String getImagePath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] campos = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, campos, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Só que a mensagem que era para ser exibida, aparece em branco e não o caminho :S .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver a obter a imagem da Galeria usando `Intent.ACTION_PICK` pode, no método `onActivityResult()`, usar `Uri imageUri = intent.getData();` para obter o *Uri* aos dados da imagem. Use o método `getImagePath()` para ler o *path* dela.

```
private String imagePath;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
            Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
            imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri)
            ......
            ......
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public String getImagePath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] campos = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, campos, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Ola Ramaral, editei o meu post com a sua resposta e deixei o meu código do seguinte jeito. Só que ainda esta dando problema, não sei se eu que sou muito leigo e não entendo ou  realmente não deu, por favor, se puder me ajudar de acordo com o meu código acima, serei muito grato

Comment: Você está a usar `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` e a criar um *Chooser*, note que o meu código só funciona se estiver a usar a app *Gallery* do Android.

Comment: Isso, so que eh em um ImageButton, ai o usuario pega da galeria a imagem,  aparece no ImageButton, logo em seguida ele aperta o botao de cadastrar e salva no banco o caminho daquela imagem

Comment: Editei o método `getImagePath()`

Comment: Eu usei o seu método modificado getImagePath  só que esta me voltando vazio ainda, eu vejo que esta vazio usando:  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Estive a testar o código, indo buscar uma imagem à **GALERIA**, e ele funciona bem.