# Qual a diferença entre File Uri, Content Uri e StringPath?

Tags: android

Meu aplicativo lida com gravação e leitura de arquivos, e eu estou um pouco confuso sobre como e quando usar cada um desses tipos de Uri.

Acredito que o melhor seria entender a diferença entre esses pra descobrir quando seria o uso correto de cada um.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## O que são:

- [File URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)  e [Content URI](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContentURIs) são [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), identificam um determinado *resource*.
- Path, normalmente na forma de uma *string*, identifica uma localização num "sistema de ficheiros(File System)". Indica o caminho, através da hierarquia de pasta, até um ficheiro.

## Qual usar:

- Qualquer um deles pode ser usado para identificar um arquivo no dispositivo.
  O que determina o uso de um ou de outro é o meio(api/classe/método) que vai usar para obtê-lo.
- Exemplos:

  - A classe [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) tem um construtor que recebe um "StringPath" e outro que recebe um URI.
    No entanto, o URI deve ter um *scheme* igual a  `file:`, tem de ser um File Uri.
  - Um Content Uri pode identificar uma imagem na galeria e [ser usado para obter o *path* até ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69353/2541).

    ```
    public String getImagePath(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] campos = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, campos, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
    ```
- Aplicações *target* Android N(API level 24) não poderão expor File URI's para fora da aplicação. Se uma *intent* contiver um URI desse tipo será lançada uma `FileUriExposedException`.
  [Nesse caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187119/2541) deverá ser usado um URI do tipo Content URI e conceder a ele uma permissão temporária de acesso.